# Posting an answer doesn't refresh the page?

Tags: bug

I was about to post this to MSE when I found that I can't reproduce it on any other SE sites, so I end up here.

On Stack Overflow, when I post an answer on my browser, sometimes the page doesn't refresh (after 10 secs). <s>In that case I think the answer isn't successfully submitted, so I hit "Post Answer" again.</s> But I am often replied with

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - This post appears to be a duplicate of [Link to the answer I have just posted]

And sometimes when I try to edit my answer, I end up posting twice. This can be annoying despite the fact that I can delete duplicated posts myself.

**Edit**: Sometimes I only need to hit the <kbd>Post Answer</kbd> button **only once**: There's even no need for a bad network environment (it occurs even under a perfect network).

[image: Desktop Screenshot]
[image: Mobile Screenshot]

---

**Environment**:

Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 64-bit desktop, Firefox 57.0.3 (64-bit) and Edge on Windows 10.

Google Chrome from 52.0.2743.100 to 63.0.3239.111 (inclusive) from Google Play, Android 7.1.1.